# Run php artisan from one Laravel install to another

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

We have a Laravel deployment website set up under *deploy.mysite.com* which handles deployments for a multitude of other websites.

One other website I'm trying to deploy which is also a Laravel site resides under *site2.myothersite.com*.

Both are on the same server. Deploy calls a script on site2, this deploy script runs various commands after `cd`'ing to the project directory. We use the following to update the database structure.

```
php artisan migrate --force
```

Ordinarily when this is run directly via SSH when in the project root, it runs just fine.

However when this is run via the deployment script (using php `exec()` to run these commands) the process does work - however, **instead of updating the project that we've `cd`'d into, it updates the database structure of the deployment site!**

It seems as if the `php artisan migrate` command ignores the fact I've `cd`'d  into another project and it takes the database values from the current directory.

How can I go about changing this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After playing around with multiple different solutions I eventually came to realise that the problem was the `.env` file from the project that I was in was setting the environment variables and then weren't being overwritten by anything therefore was then essentially running the code as the wrong site.

**What I did to solve this**

In my deploy script I manually loaded up the `.env` file and overwrote the environment variables with `overload` rather than just `load`.
**Note:** This will only work on versions below V5.

```
$dotenv = Dotenv::create(__DIR__);
$dotenv->overload();
```

**UPDATE for V5**

As per [@nibnut's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63230002/871150), since dotenv V5 (now in Laravel 7.0) this loads the environment variables as immutable. In my case I'm happy to allow these to be mutable, in which case I can do the following instead of the above.

```
$dotenv = Dotenv::createMutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
```

https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv#immutability-and-repository-customization

This was all I had to do to get my original script working.

**NOTE:** as this is a laravel install at all ends, the [dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) package was already installed. This could be used for any project by installing it separately.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `cd` to the directory, you could change the command to something similar to this:

`php /var/www/sitea/artisan migrate --force`

That will run the artisan command for the provided directory.

Comment: This is something I have actually tried - I also double checked it just now, unfortunately I get the same result. I wiped the database first, and instead of creating the tables, it failed, telling me that a users table already exists (which it does on the deploy site), so even running the command as above it's still trying to run it on a different install.

Comment: Did you check to make sure the .env file in the site contains the correct database credentials?

Answer (score 1):

```
$log = shell_exec("unset DB_HOST &&
       unset DB_PORT && 
       unset DB_PASSWORD && 
       unset DB_USERNAME && 
       unset DB_DATABASE && 
       composer dump-autoload &&
       cd /var/www/yourproject/ && php /var/www/yourproject/artisan migrate:fresh &&
       php /var/www/yourproject/artisan db:seed &&
       php /var/www/yourproject/artisan seed:translation");
```

Answer (score 1):

novocaine's answer unfortunately no longer works in Laravel 7.x, since the DotEnv file is loaded immutable.

My current workaround is to create a temporary .env file in my project (i.e. ".env.temp") then use the --env argument when calling my artisan commands:

`php artisan migrate --env=temp`

This may not work for all use cases, but if you're calling artisan commands in project B from within project A, it should work fine.

Comment: I've not ran this with a 7.x install yet, but this looks like a good solution 

Comment: I've now ran into this problem and have updated my answer. Initialising as mutable can also work IF that's ok for your environment - `$dotenv = Dotenv::createMutable(__DIR__);  
$dotenv->load();`

Comment: Yep - the createMutable option works very well too - thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

novocaine's answer involve reloading .env file. But you can also empty environment variables with `env -i`.

This method will avoid having some variables not overwritten due to different `.env` file variable name. For example, your deployment site may have a variable called `DEPLOY_KEY` in the `.env` that is non-existent on the `.env` of site2. Reloading `.env` file may leave the `DEPLOY_KEY` variable available on the site2 script. This may leads into security issues.

So, instead of running

```
exec('php artisan migrate --force');
```

you'll have just to add `env -i`:

```
exec('env -i php artisan migrate --force');
```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48995/375005

Comment: This is way cleaner than any of the other answers!